# Merging master branch to feature branch and then pushing to new repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a feature branch checked out on which I have made many changes that I havent pushed to master yet. Out repo was on gitlab, but it has locked out because we exceeded max user limits. So we cannot push to this repo anymore, though we can pull. Now the team has decided to move to github and it might take some time to move the repo to github.

My doubt is can I merge master branch to feature branch locally and then commit it to github once the migration from gitlab to github completes? If yes, can you please give some overview of the process or at least link of some webpage discussing the same?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to merge and push? Git does not care if you push to GitLab, GitHub, Bitbucket or an arbitrary plain repo. What are your concerns exactly?

Comment: I have never done this, so why am not aware that its very much possible. Am not aware of whether all branches will get migrated to github. I guess its all about changing the origin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a *mirror* of a repository, you can specify the `--mirror` flag to both [`clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) and [`push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git clone --mirror /path/to/old/repo
cd repo
git push --mirror /path/to/new/repo
```

This will clone all refs (branches, tags, notes) into a local bare repository and then push all local refs to the remote repository.

Finally, you can clone that remote repository like any other repository.